# What is the difference between fire cement and fire concrete?

Tags: concrete

I am trying to build a foundry. The Youtube video refers to 4:1 Perlite:Fire Cement. But the shop also offers Fire Concrete. I don't know what's the difference.

Could someone please explain the difference?

Link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTPdybtO-a0

Comment: I've not used either in any of my brews. Is this a brewing question?

Comment: It's a "casting metal" or "foundry building" question. I couldn't use the tags "foundry" "casting" because the site didn't let me. ... Oooh, wait .. "homebrewing" as in "beer brewing" and not in "homebrewing equipment" ... This is .. embarrassing :(

Comment: Can you insert a link to the video? If you don't have the rep, paste the url as a comment, and one of us will do it for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR; - Concrete is poured into a form, for structural members.  Cement is spread as a glue.

Cement is a glue.  Concrete is a mix of aggregates, held together with cement.

If you're building something structural (to support a load -- such as itself), you'd buy the concrete.  If you're using it as a skim/finish coat, or to attach firebrick, buy the cement, and (possibly) mix it with some very fine aggregates - depending on the use.

See this answer for more detail on cement/concrete in general. [What actually happens if I vary proportions of cement and sand in mortar?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6651/what-actually-happens-if-i-vary-proportions-of-cement-and-sand-in-mortar/6655#6655)

EDIT: After seeing the video, I now understand.  What you are making is a light, weak concrete using the cement and perlite as an aggregate.  You need to buy the fire cement, not the concrete. (You could use concrete and omit the perlite, but I think it would be pretty heavy.)

Comment: Thank you! What will be more temperature resistant as I don't want to melt aluminium but brass and bronze which has a higher melting point than aluminium.

Comment: I think the perlite mix will be better insulated. It might keep the outside a bit cooler.